# How to get sum of particular column (custom model)?

Tags: collection, model

I have custom model with 4 fields(a,b,c,d).
I need sum of "d" field.
So my solution using collection loop the d values and make the sum.For this is any simple solution?
Thanks in advance.

```
  $available=0;
    $pieces = Mage::getResourceModel('rad_inventorypieces/piece_collection')
    foreach($pieces as piece)
    {

$available=+$piece->getAvailable();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to implement new method in class of `rad_inventorypieces/piece` resource model

Method might look like this:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getSumD()
{
    $select = $this->getReadConnection()
        ->select()
        ->from($this->getMainTable(), array('sum' => new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(d)')));

    return $this->getReadConnection()->fetchOne($select)
}
```

Comment: Call to undefined method Rad_Inventorypieces_Model_Resource_Piece_Collection::getReadConnection()

Comment: You need to implement it not in collection model, but in resource model `Rad_Inventorypieces_Model_Resource_Piece`

Comment: its working.on that i need to add filter.now addtfieldtofilter undefined method error.So can i add where clause

Comment: Yes, it is not a collection anymore and you can not use addtFieldToFilter method. Use `where` instead